# MongoDB custom Query in Spring Data Mongo

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Someone can help me make a Query(Mongo), with new in Mongodb type(example):

```
@Override
public Long maxCodigoSecuencia() {
final Query query = new Query().limit(1).with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "codigo_secuencia"));
Oportunidad oportunidad = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Oportunidad.class);
return oportunidad.getCodidoSecuencia();
```

}

Entity(MongoDB):

```
Opportunity
  String commercial (id)
  String statu  ( enum)
  String product  ( id)
```

Dto filter:

```
dtoFilter
  List<String> commercial (id of comercial)
  List<String> statu ( enum of status)
  List<String> product ( id of product)
```

I get from front a dtoFilter with a list of commercial id, a string listing with state enumerated and a string listing with product id. That I look for all the "Opportunities" that coincide with the listings (an AND)

Someone can help me with the search query.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `$or` criteria for each of the document.

Something like

```
@Override
public List<Oportunidad> getOportunidads(DtoFilter dtoFilter) {
    List<String> commercial = dtoFilter.getCommercial();
    List<String> statu = dtoFilter.getStatu();
    List<String> product = dtoFilter.getProduct();
    List<Criteria> andCriteria = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i < commercial.size(); i++) {
        andCriteria.add(Criteria.where("commercial").is(commercial.get(i)).and("statu").is(statu.get(i)).and("product").is(product.get(i)));
    }
    Criteria orCriteria = new Criteria().orOperator(andCriteria.toArray(new Criteria[andCriteria.size()]));
    return mongoTemplate.find(new Query().addCriteria(orCriteria), Oportunidad.class);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but "mongoOperations" what is it, how I instantiate it

Comment: Sorry its `mongoTemplate`. Updated.